# Help for series calculation $\sum_{n\ge1} \frac{1}{4n^3-n}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to find the following series.

$$\sum_{n\ge1} \frac{1}{4n^3-n}$$

So, fisrt of all, patial fraction : $$\frac{1}{4n^3-n}=\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{n}.$$

Next, I consider the geometric series $$\sum_{n\ge1} x^{2n-2}+x^{2n}-x^{n-1}=\frac{1}{1-x^2}+\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}-\frac{1}{1-x}\tag{1}$$ where ${-1\lt x\lt1}$.

Then, I integrate both side of (1) from $0$ to $1$:

$$\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{1}{2n-1}+\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{n}=\int_0^1 \frac{x^2-x}{1-x^2}dx$$

Finally, I get the value that is equal to $ln(2)-1$  by improper integral but it's less than $0$. What did I do wrong? All help is appreciated.

Comment: it seems that this sum is not so easy to compute

Comment: This series is telescopic? I can't do it with telescopic.

Comment: @XTL Telescope it how, exactly?

Comment: To be clear: are you asking specifically for the method your\ are suggesting (once fixed/massaged), or are you open to other techniques? (e.g., I have one involving partial sums and the Harmonic series, yielding $2\ln2 -1$).

Comment: (I would say, without checking too carefully, that the issue in your step most likely resides in the "I integrate both sides of (1) from 0 to 1." You integrate the LHS termwise -- why can you do that? The interval of convergence is $1$, so it is not obvious you can swap $\sum$ and $\int_0^1$. And, as it turns out, worse than "not obvious" it seems to be wrong)

Comment: please, show all your techniques. @ClementC.

Comment: Your integration in $\sum_{n\ge1} x^{2n-2}+x^{2n}-x^{n-1}$ isn't valid.  First item not defined integration.

Comment: How? @MyGlasses. I have already integrated from 0 to 1.

Comment: @MoNtiDeaDMoonDogs See below.

Comment: $$ \begin{align} &\frac{1}{4n^3-n}=\frac{1}{2n-1}+\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{\color{red}{2}}{\color{red}{2}\,n}\\ &\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[x^{2n-2}+x^{2n}-\color{red}{2}\,x^{\color{red}{2}n-1}\right]=\frac{1}{1-x^2}+\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}-\frac{2\,x}{1-x^2}=\frac{(1-x)^2}{1-x^2}=\frac{1-x}{1+x}\\ &\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4\,n^3-n}=\int_0^1\frac{1-x}{1+x}\,dx=\color{red}{2\log{2}-1} \end{align} $$

Comment: What is different between $\frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{2}{2n}$ for calculation? Why do you did like this?.@HazemOrabi

Comment: @MoNtiDeaDMoonDogs It changes the behavior of the series: $\sum_n x^{n-1}$ does not have the same behavior near $1$ as  $\sum_n x^{2n-1}$ does. This is a neat trick, a bit like magic; but wouldn't be seen as a rigorous proof (at least by me as a TA) unless you do explain *why* this swapping series/integral is fine, while the previous one is not.

Comment: $$ \begin{align} \frac{1}{4n^3-n} &=\frac{1}{2n-1}+\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{n} \\ &=\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{\color{red}{2}}{\color{red}{2}\,n}\\ &=\left[\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{\color{red}{1}}{\color{red}{2}\,n}\right] + \left[\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{\color{red}{1}}{\color{red}{2}\,n}\right] \end{align} $$

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Following a comment of mine above:*

- without checking too carefully, the issue in your step most likely resides in the *"I integrate both sides of (1) from 0 to 1."* You then integrate the LHS termwise -- *why* can you do that? The interval of convergence of your power series is $1$, so it is *not* obvious you can swap $\sum_n$ and $\int_0^1$. And, as it turns out, worse than "not obvious" it appears to be wrong.
- Now, another approach to compute the sum: starting with your $(1)$, we write, for $N\geq 1$,
  $$\begin{align}
  \sum_{n=1}^N a_n &= \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{2n+1}+\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{2n-1}-\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n}\\
  &= \sum_{n=1}^N \left(\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n}\right)+\sum_{n=1}^N \left(\frac{1}{2n-1}+\frac{1}{2n}\right)-2\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n} \\
  &= \sum_{n=2}^{2N+1} \frac{1}{n}+\sum_{n=1}^{2N} \frac{1}{n}-2\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n} \\
  &= H_{2N+1}-1+H_{2N}-2H_N \\
  &= \ln(2N+1)+\ln(2N)-2\ln N - 1 +o(1)\\
  &= 2\ln 2 - 1 + \ln(N+\frac{1}{2})+ \ln(N+\frac{1}{2})-2\ln N +o(1)\\
  &= 2\ln 2 - 1 + \ln\frac{N+\frac{1}{2}}{N}+ \ln\frac{N-\frac{1}{2}}{N} +o(1)\\
  &\xrightarrow[N\to\infty]{} \boxed{2\ln 2 -1}
  \end{align}$$
  where $H_N = \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n}$ denotes the $N$-th [Harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number), which [satisfies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Rate_of_divergence)
  $$
  H_N = \ln N + \gamma + o(1)
  $$
  when $N\to\infty$ ($\gamma$ being Euler's constant). We also used that by continuity of the logarithm, $\ln\frac{N\pm\frac{1}{2}}{N} \xrightarrow[N\to\infty]{} \ln 1=0$.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: I have one more question. When can I swap $\sum$ and $\int$ ?
I see some problems that I can swap such as $\sum_{n\ge1} \frac{1}{(2n)(2n+1)}$.

Comment: I don't think there are full, simple answers for that, but there are some cases where this can be done: (1) power series, *inside* the radius of convergence (so here, you could have, if you had integrated from $0$ to $0.999$, for instance); (2) when you have uniform convergence of the series of function on the interval you integrate on; (3) whenever you can apply, say, the Dominated Convergence theorem to the sequence of functions defined by the partial sums of the series. (These are only three of, I don't doubt it, many cases -- also, three of the most useful, I'd say.)

Comment: normally I solve the problems like this by integration but I just saw the mistake of my solution.
Many thanks for your advice and solution.

Comment: @MoNtiDeaDMoonDogs I review your proof, and it's very beautiful for me at least, but for divergence $\sum\dfrac1n$ which concludes be equal to $\ln2$ has a serious fault, so it's not applicable. good job.

Comment: @MyGlasses Are you talking to the OP, or to me? If the latter, I do not understand the point you are making.

Comment: With OP, sorry very long comments make me mistake.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this way. It is easier. Let
$$ f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{4n^3-n}x^{2n+1}. $$
Then $f(1)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{4n^3-n}$ and
$$ f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n-1)n}x^{2n}, f''(x)=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n-1)}x^{2n-1}, f'''(x)=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{2n-2}=\frac2{1-x^2}$$
and hence
$$ f(1)=\int_0^1\int_0^s\int_0^t\frac2{1-x^2}dxdtds=2\ln2-1.$$

Comment: Beauty is Simplicity. (+1)